# Why fork() use the same variable but different value?

Tags: c++, c++11, fork

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                                                                                                                            
#include <unistd.h>

void f(int&);
void g(int&);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("--beginning of program\n");

    int counter = 0;
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) {
        f(counter);
        printf("child process: %d, %p", counter, &counter);
    } else if (pid>0) {
        g(counter);
        for (int i=0; i<5; ++i) {
            sleep(1);
            printf("parent process: %d, %p\n", counter, &counter);
        }
    }
    printf("--end of program--\n");
    return 0;
}

void f(int& counter) {
    counter = 1;
    printf("in f: %d, %p-\n", counter, &counter);
}
void g(int& counter){
}
```

and here's the result:

```
--beginning of program
in f: 1, 0x7ffc9b01c6a4-
child process: 1, 0x7ffc9b01c6a4--end of program--
parent process: 0, 0x7ffc9b01c6a4
parent process: 0, 0x7ffc9b01c6a4
parent process: 0, 0x7ffc9b01c6a4
parent process: 0, 0x7ffc9b01c6a4
parent process: 0, 0x7ffc9b01c6a4
--end of program--
```

Clearly in child process it's the same parameter with the same address, but the value is different.

Why is it happening?

Comment: Try to avoid terms like "clearly" when you're wrong ;)

Answer (score 10):

**Each process has its own *virtual memory space*.**

That means `0x7ffc9b01c6a4` in one process is entirely unrelated to `0x7ffc9b01c6a4` in another.

This is not the same object; it's an object in the new process. Since the second process was forked from the first one, essentially cloning the process, it's not a surprise that objects should exist in the same virtual memory location in the second as they were in the first.

Answer (score 3):

This is the basis of the `fork()`, and this is exactly what allows it to work. To understand this, you need to remember that all address space of the process in modern operation systems is virtual - which means, it has nothing to do with actual physical memory addressess. Gone are the days when access to the memory at address 0x8000 (if I remember the address correctly) went straight to the video memory. I used to program this way, and instead of screen manipulation routines just wrote values in video memory, which was much faster. This was fun :)

But it is no more. Now in user programms the address has nothing to do with physical memory, and whenever you are access memory at locaiton '0x1234567' the translation is made. The CPU knows how to map this virtual address to the physical memory address, but noone else does.

So, when you fork your process, an exact memory replica is made. It has the same virtual addresses (because memory replica is exact!). But since it is a difference process now, the CPU will translate those virtual addresses to different physical memory addressess. At least, this is semantics. In real modern systems, the exact memory replica will not be really happening — or `fork()` would take too long. Instead, the memory is marked as 'copy-on-write'. Which means that untill the data is modified, two processess will be accessing the same physical memory. But as soon as any process modifies the memory, it will actually be copied and now everybody will have their own copy.

Comment: Good point about COW. Of course, even after the copy, the address would _still_ be the same :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, VIRTUAL address will be the same, of course.

Comment: The address seen by the OP yeah.